# Laravel select object as property

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I'd like to know if it is possible to do a left join in a query and if it exists instead of having all the columns in the same "level" make the joined table go as a property (This without any relationships)

For example

```
$users = user::leftJoin("posts","users.id","=","posts.user_id")->get();
```

Instead of returning every field together,

```
["id"/*This actually gets messed up if select doesn't choose which to use*/,
  "name",
  "age",
  /*Now post fields*/
  "tile",
  "date_posted"
  ...
]
```

and having it return

```
["id",
  "name",
  "age",
  "post"=>[
    "id",
    "tile",
    "date_posted"
    ...
   ]
]
```

Edit: If possible to avoid loops for obvious reasons... I know it is possible and in last resort will use them but not using loops would help out a lot

Comment: No, it's not possible (like that). That's exactly why you should use relationships for this instead of join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using eloquent for the users table. Why not use relationships? It does exactly what you want. Create a new `Post` model. Then add the following relationship to your `User` model.

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

You can now fetch the users with post like so

```
$users = User::with('posts')->get();
```

The result is exactly what you want. Also I've used `User` in my example, where as you've used `user`. The result would contain the posts object as `posts` instead of `post` as you've shown in the example, you can change this property name by changing the relationship method name. I've used these since they're the right convention.

Comment: I used user and posts as an example.

Comment: @SérgioReis you can swap this out with any other type of similar relation and you'd get the same result.

Comment: In the actual sitiuation imagine like, a user has a type, lets say $user->id_type, and sometimes the id_type is null (there is no association yet)

Comment: There are multiple types of relationships and each one has different conditions through which you can pull data. For example you can use `has` and `whereHas` to pull only the users with posts or posts with specific condition. In this case a user has many posts and the posts belong to a user. The example is to showcase that you can actually get the format of result you need. Even if the relationship differs there's always a way to get the desired result with related data. You should read more about it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Pretty sure i could've gave a better example, the relationship is more one-to-one (one user has one type) than one to many (one user has many posts), still, the problem using elequent relationships is that it seems to me that they're taking a big toll to use and thus wanted to try out using joins that actually are making things smoother. Anyways you're answer is obviously the most correct of the badly asked question. Thanks.

Comment: One-to-one becomes even more easier and straightforward. In this example all laravel does with eloquent is fetches the user and then fetches the posts of the user and attaches them as single result. You're not losing anything by using this over joins. In fact it becomes much more readable and data more consumable.